# how to create trapezium with border like below attached image in link with the borders beside it as straight line

Tags: css

create trapezium with border  like below attached image in link with the borders beside it as straight line]

[image]

able to create trapezium shape but unable to create the long border with straight line and then border for trapezium.

Comment: Can you share your current css so everyone here can better help?

Answer (score 0):

If the background of the shape is solid and opaque, then you can easily accomplish the task using a pseudo-element with gradients:

```css
.tab {
  position: relative;
  height: 120px; width: 400px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #ffc902, inset 0 0 0 100vw #000;
}
.tab::before {
  content: attr(data-title);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 10px; z-index: 1;
  display: grid; place-items: center;
  height: 26px; width: 240px;
  transform: translatey(-100%);
  color: white;
  background: 
    50% 0 / calc(100% - 44px) 100% linear-gradient(180deg, #ffc902 0 4px, #000 4px), 
    100% 0 / 26px 100% linear-gradient( to left bottom, #0000 calc(50% - 4px), #ffc902 calc(50% - 3px) 50%, #000 calc(50% + 1px)), 
    0 0 / 26px 100% linear-gradient( to right bottom, #0000 calc(50% - 4px), #ffc902 calc(50% - 3px) 50%, #000 calc(50% + 1px));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* Only for example --> */ body{margin:0;min-height:100vh;background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9NKc.png),radial-gradient(#fff8,#000f);display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;background-repeat:no-repeat}
```

```html
<div class="tab" data-title="First Tab"></div>
```